# Why is precision lost if resolving of the type left to the compiler?

Tags: abap, netweaver

What is the reason of the lost of precision if the decimal type of the variable is left to be defined by the compiler? Is this documented anywhere?

```
DATA: gv_1 TYPE p LENGTH 15 DECIMALS 2 VALUE '56555.31'.
DATA: gv_2 TYPE p LENGTH 15 DECIMALS 2 VALUE '56555.31'.
DATA: gv_3 TYPE p LENGTH 15 DECIMALS 2 VALUE '56555.34'.

DATA(gv_sum) = gv_1 + gv_2 + gv_3. "data type left to be resolved by the compiler

WRITE / gv_sum.

DATA: gv_sum_exp TYPE p LENGTH 15 DECIMALS 2. "explicit type declaration
gv_sum_exp = gv_1 + gv_2 + gv_3.

WRITE / gv_sum_exp.
```

The first sum results in

> 169666

The second one in

> 169665.96

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we know, the ABAP compiler brings all the operands of an arithmetic expression to the so-called [calculation type](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenarith_type.htm). And we also know that data type with the *largest value range* determines the whole caclulation type. 
But you, probably, don't aware of some changes that were introduced to this process with the release of inline declarations in ABAP. Here they are:

> If operands are specified as generically typed field symbols or formal
>   parameters and an inline declaration `DATA(var)` is used as the target
>   field of an assignment, the generic types contribute to the statically
>   detectable calculation type (used to determine the data type of the
>   declaration) as follows: 
> ...
> csequence, clike, c, n, and p like p. If no type with a higher priority is involved, **the type p with length 8** (**no decimal places**) is used for the declaration.
> ...

That is exactly what we see in debugger during execution of your code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be really dangerous though. :|

Comment: Seems to me that if someone needs precision it is good practice to explicitly define the type with all the decimals expected. I generally prefer to type my variables.

Comment: @Jagger, you're welcome. And don't hesitate to mark answer as right ^)